# Changes made in custom.css not getting Reflected in LIferay Theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am creating a liferay theme and I am using portal_normal.vm to create template.
Onf problem I have is I dont understand from where and how the variables in templates e. $name are passed to the template.

Secondly the changes made to custom.css in _diffs folder are not relected in portal_normal.css which is also in _diffs folder.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect you mean the files

```
/docroot/_diffs/css/custom.css
/docroot/_diffs/templates/portal_normal.vm
```

Then build the theme (ant) and deploy the resulting theme and you should be done. But you definitely need the directories. The files given above will be copied to

```
/docroot/css/custom.css
/docroot/templates/portal_normal.vm
```

in the ant build process, and that should be everything that you need.

Note that you mention portal_normal.**css** - is this a typo in your question or the root cause for your problem?